# Alternative way for goto statement in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, goto

Here's the link for the flowchart:
http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o530/HTHVampire/C%20plus%20plus/Capture_zps5a6c3acf.jpg

[image]

Here's the code for the flowchart as shown, just ignore the ambiguous statement in the flowchart.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare and initialize a variable
    int a = 0;
    //prompt user for a value
    cout << "please enter a value" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    again1:
    //enter a decision block
    if(a > 10)
    {
        if(a < 10)
        {
            again2:
            if(a < 100)
            {
                a = a - 3;
                goto again2;
            }
            else goto again1;
        }
        else
        {
            a = a - 7;
            goto again1;
        }
    }
    else cout << "the output is " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

May I know that can I play this code with if-else statement together with while statement? instead of goto statement.

Thanks for your guides!

Comment: How can `a` be less than 10 if `a` is greater than 10?

Comment: @chris This guy uses `goto` in C++. Don't have high expectations.

Comment: To @OP: `for`, `while` or `do` loops...

Comment: Equivalent to your code as far as I can tell: `std::cin >> a; while (a > 10) a -= 7; std::cout << ...`

Comment: Ya, u are right, the flaw in the flowchart can be ignored... =)

Comment: You should not ignore mistakes in a flowchart. The flowchart should be correct, otherwise you'll have inconsistencies or just bad code.

Comment: more like flow in the flawchart!!!!11

Answer (score 6):

This structure should do the core logic according to the flowchart:

```
while (a > 10) {
    if (a < 10) {
        while (a < 100) {
            a += 3;
        }
    } else {
        a -= 7;
    }
}
```

Note that the `if` test is absurd. However, I didn't draw the flowchart; I just reproduced it in code.

Comment: `while (a <= 10)` should be `while (a < 10)`

Comment: @Devolus - Actually, it should be `while (a > 10)`. I misread the branches in the flowchart.

Comment: http://codepad.org/Hfa2X4QR

this is the code that I wrote earlier on...but sadly it doesn't work. no error when compiling, just the program hang when I enter the value like 60.

Comment: @Asus93 Did you try stepping through with a debugger watching what happened to the value of `a` while you stepped?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Thanks for your hints, ya, there's something wrong, cause if let's say the value is 60, this value will never be false and it cannot be displayed. due to the flaw with the flowchart above, I hardly to  test it well... That's why.
If ignore the flawness in the chart, the code that I wrote is it acceptable?(as a beginner)...

Comment: @Asus93: IMHO yes but... your code has a three things you should consider. 1) Don't use the `goto`. There are a couple good arguments towards its use in very isolated areas. I disagree. 2) Don't use `using namespace std;`. It has the potential to cause "collisions" with other code. If you like you can use a series of `using`s like `using std::cout;` and `using std::cin;`. 3) Don't hard code "magic" numbers; declare `const` variables instead. Numbers have no meaning by themselves with the exception of `1` or `0`(generally). Your formatting is good and you're not returning `void`:)

Comment: @Asus93 - The code in your question should eventually print a value if you enter 60. Each time that outer `if` tests true, the `if (a < 10)` test fails and the `else` branch subtracts 7 from the value of `a`. Eventually `a` will be reduced to where the outer `if` test fails and the value of `a` will be printed. Note that you have an error in the body of the innermost `if`: the line `a = a - 3;` should (according to the flowchart) be `a = a + 3;`.

Comment: @TedHopp what if I use this code where I compile it at first? http://codepad.org/Hfa2X4QR

I would not like to use goto statement.

Comment: @Asus93 - The code in that link doesn't follow the flowchart. It also will loop infinitely for any input above 50. The inner `while` loop will increase `a` to at least 100; after that, the outer loop will run forever, entering the `if` branch at each iteration where the inner `while` loop will do nothing. It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: @TedHopp Hi, thanks for guiding about the questions.
thanks guys for your answers, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with goto so long as you restrict use to state machines.
Many teachers erroneously ban use of it for lack of understanding.
For simple state machines like yours, and protocol decoding, it produces extremely readable code. I ruined years of embedded C routines because I was afraid to use goto.

I started using goto and my finger paintings turned into Van Gogh.

Comment: The hysterical aversion to the `goto` statement so common in this industry is absurd. Sure, `goto` can be abused, just like all the other flow control statements, but it can also be used properly. Even more prone to abuse are exceptions, but somehow they're the darling everyone loves, even if they are just a disguised `goto`. 

Those who refuse to use it under any circumstance are ignorant and immature.

Comment: disguised goto-- I'll have to think about that one.