# What to use instead of Goto Statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement, goto

I'm wondering what I should be using instead of goto statements?

Should I be using nested if/while/do-while statements?

They say that using goto creates 'spaghetti code', but surely if someone is writing a large console application and they have if statement after if statement in an attempt to control the flow, that's going to make a mess?

I'm asking as many people have asked why the goto statement is bad, but not what to replace it with. I'm sure a lot of beginners could do with this.

This is for C++.

Comment: From what I've seen, loops, functions, or RAII.

Comment: It depends on what you currently use goto statements *for*. Show us some code, or describe what you would use a goto for.

Comment: @chris ... not to mention `switch`, `break`, `continue`, etc.

Comment: Remember that code can often be replaced with data, and vice versa. For example, if the control flow is either in branch A or branch B of an if-else, then this corresponds to a boolean variable `condition_A_is_true`. And vice versa. A large switch often corresponds to an array. So on.

Comment: Congratulations, you've created a storm! If you want to get more info, please look at the Wikipedia page "Goto"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative way for goto statement in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509953/alternative-way-for-goto-statement-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are much better off using functions, loops, and conditional statements.  Use break and continue as necessary.

I can nearly guarantee you any situation in which you are utilizing goto there is a better alternative.  There is one notable exception to this: multi-level break.

```
while(1){
    while(1){
        goto breakOut;
    }
    //more code here?
}
breakOut:
```

In this one (relatively) rare situation, goto can be used in place of a typical "break" to make it clear we are actually getting out of a nested loop.  The other way to approach this is with a "done" variable:

```
while(!done){
    while(!done){
        done = true;
        break;
    }
    if(done){break;}
    //More code here?  If so, the above line is important!
}
```

As you can see, the done variable is more verbose when you have additional processing in outer loops, so a goto is a cleaner way of breaking free!

However, in 99% of cases you really, really, don't want to start writing a bunch of goto statements.  Really think through each one.

With functions the above could also be written like so:

```
bool innerLoop(){
    while(1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

...
while(innerLoop()){ //can only be written this way if the inner loop is the first thing that should run.
    //More code here?
}
...
```

Sometimes breaking an inner loop out in this way can be messy if there are a lot of dependencies on the outer one.  But it remains a viable way of breaking out of code early with return statements instead of goto or break.

Comment: This is quite clearly a minimal simplified example.  No work is being done, I just wanted to show how to break out of a loop.  It represents a very real and viable pattern, however.  Consider the outer loop could be: "iterate over text files in a directory", and then the inner loop could be "file contains matching text".  In this case instead of calling the method "innerLoop" it would be "fileContainsText" where it iterates over the contents and returns true if so (and thus breaking out of both loops since the file is found).  Your flippant remark is not productive.

Comment: It's productive when you take it at face value rather than defensively and falsely ascribing sarcasm to it that was not intended. Your answer is based on the assertion that this pattern is clearer and more intuitive than a set of `goto`s, but that seems not to be the case. If you wish to demonstrate this, perhaps use an example that doesn't demonstrate the opposite! :)

Comment: The emphasis on "so" makes it look sarcastic.  Regardless, that's a fair point, but I suppose my follow up comment addresses the issue you had?

Comment: To a degree, but it's still not obvious to me that this is automatically better than a `goto` solution, beyond religious reasons.

Comment: I am primarily showing concrete options.  I think the goto in a multi level break can be more appropriate in some cases, as I said if the inner loop is tightly coupled to the outer one its hard to make a meaningful function out of the inner one.  This becomes very true when the inner needs access to several variables in the outer and it would be as much code writing the parameter list as the function body.  I am only offering information and caution against liberal goto use, not advocating against goto when it makes sense.

Comment: I would like to point out I never said option 3 was automatically better than option 1.  Re read my post with a neutral tone.

Comment: Yes and that's fine. I haven't downvoted your answer, nor said that it's bad. Re-read my comments with a neutral tone. :)

Answer (score 3):

Don’t listen to people who say "never use `goto`". You're quite right that there are cases where nesting scoped blocks will make a heck of a lot more mess than a `goto`. It has its place, just as a `switch`/`case` does. *However*, with functions you can often refactor away the entire argument and keep people happy.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted into oblivion? Avoiding `goto` doesn't make code better 100% of the time.

Comment: Well this should get interesting ;)

Comment: that... wasn't really what he was asking.The question wasn't "should I always and forever, 100% of the time, avoid `goto`. It was simply "so, if we should prefer to avoid goto, what do I do *instead*? Saying "nah, go ahead and use gotos" is missing the point, not answering the question, and leading him in the wrong direction

Comment: In C, goto is the only sane way to do error handling. In C++ the more idiomatic way is to use RAII.

Comment: @Lightness is right, `goto` has it's valid uses (even if these are rare). No reason to downvote!

Comment: @jalf, With the answer, I'm seeing it as more the OP discovered **never** to use `goto`, and the answer stating that such advice isn't always a solution. Sort of like an XY problem if you will. Of course the opposite isn't always (is practically never) true either, and the question still holds for that.

Comment: @asveikau but the question isn't about C, and it isn't about error handling. It isn't about any specific situation where a goto may make sense. It is a completely general and broad question asking what the alternative is. This question does not explain any of the alternatives. He is effectively asking "how should I structure my program, if not with gotos", and the most upvoted answer is "JUST USE GOTOS, IT'LL BE FINE"? And people are surprised to see it downvoted?

Comment: All constructs are there for a reason.  Use it if it makes the coding easier to understand.

Comment: I legitimately don't understand why this has 9 upvotes thoughts. It's just someone saying "I think there are uses for goto" which doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: I think this is a terrible answer because it does not provide examples.  It is an opinion.  I have provided an answer *with* examples below.  Regardless of the suggestion of goto being okay or not, the answer is low quality.  I think there are a bunch of religious votes here surrounding the fact that the author says "goto is okay sometimes" and that's not the rhetoric most people are used to hearing.  Vote based on the contents though, rather than the vague idea, and it just isn't that insightful.

Comment: @jalf: If you read the _whole_ answer, you'll see that I gave an alternative suggestion, as requested. Sorry for providing background and context; next time I'll be sure not to do that, to keep you happy.

Comment: -1, doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 3):

If you can write your logic using a clean, modern construct, then use it. Otherwise, if `goto` makes sense, use it.

In general, `goto` can make your code harder to read and follow the flow of the code. For that reason, newbies are told to avoid `goto` altogether. This encourages them to think in terms of other constructs.

But some people just get religious about it. Coding is not a religion. And if a `goto` makes sense, C++ has a perfectly valid `goto` statement and you should use it when it makes good sense.

It doesn't make sense to me to ask what you should use instead of `goto`. You can generally use some type of loop or other construct, depending on what you are doing. But where `goto` makes sense, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply forget that there is the goto statement in C++ and there will not be questions about how to replace the goto.:)

As for me I never see a code with goto statement that I could call it as a good code. Usually a goto statement is the source of some kind of errors and difficulties. Especially it is difficult to modify such code. Moreover one goto statement usually starts to produce other goto statements in the code.:)

Answer (score 0):

The `goto` is bad because it allows you to jump from context to context. The context is a vector of all your variables (with their values) at a particular point of your program. A program *execution graph* shows you how your program jumps from context to context. It's in your best interests to keep the execution graph as simple as possible. The simplest one is a chain, the next step is an execution tree. A loop adds complexity, but it's a *managed* complexity. If you have a node in your execution graph, which is reachable via more than one execution path, and you need to understand a context at this node, then you'll need to follow more than one execution path back. These "merge" nodes add a lot to the complexity of your program. Each labeled statement (the `goto` target) is a potential merge node.

So, try don't use the `goto` operator at all - the language itself will **force** you to find a manageable solution using loops, boolean variables, classes, functions etc. and your program will be more clear and understandable. C++ exceptions is another manageable way to jump between contexts.

There are computing geniuses, who can keep in their minds and process very complex execution graphs, so they don't care much about complexity of their programs or a next programmer, who will be assigned to support or take over their code in the future. I guess, we have some of them here :-)

Comment: _'never (never!)'_ That's bull ...

Comment: Even the stupid MISRA C++ rules allow it, regulated for proper use.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - not for proper use, but for compatibility with old code.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev No! Not for compatibility (there's nothing stated about this). They provide a handful of rules, how to write properly used `goto` and labels placement.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - languages like Java and Python didn't have to support any legacy code. These languages don't have `goto` - and nobody complains about that

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev And what? That still doesn't make it invalid for c++, and you can't say _'never (never!)'_. It has it's valid use cases, and can be used safely, if one knows well what one does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - well, Java and Python designers couldn't find any use cases for the `goto`

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev Except Java has a multi-level break that looks suspiciously like goto.

Comment: @M2tM - Oh, yes! And I'm trying to avoid it too, when I code in Java

Comment: I don't recall writing many low-level data parsers in JavaScript or Python.